# How to prove a tiling of a hexagon must form a 3D cubic stack?

Tags: geometry, tiling, proof-without-words

How to prove that a tiling of a big hexagon consisting of triangles, using only $2$-triangle tiles (three possible orientations), must resemble a continuous, convex (for each small cube), manifold, $3$D cubic stack (i.e. a 3D staircase) if we color each orientation differently?

The original question comes from Mathologer's video from Youtube, in which he asks the question why there must be an equal number of tiles for each orientation. The answer is simple by simply projecting each faces to the "wall", if we assume all tilings can resemble a convex continuous manifold $3$D cubic stack. However this assumption does not seem obvious to me. There might be some tiling that leads to strange shapes which we cannot do the $3$D projection and we need to prove that's never happening.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I assume you mean "consisting of," not "consists of." I assume by "2-triangles tiles (three possible orientations)" you mean erasing edges so you get a bunch of rhombi colored according to their orientation. The phrase "convex continuous manifold 3D cubic stack" seems a bit mysterious to me - it doesn't seem convex in general, I guess it's a topological manifold, and you can just say "stack of cubes" for simplicity. Also you don't specify *which* Mathologer video.

Comment: Sorry for the bad English, I have fixed the words. And yes I mean stack of cubes without "holes", "floating cubes", or "non manifold edges" or any other unthinkable strange configurations.

Comment: Intuitively, if you pick one of the six directions to be "down," you can start at the bottom-most rhombus and work your way up adding rhombi to the picture, and every time you add a new rhombus the picture remains sensible.

Comment: Seriously though, I would like to know which Mathologer video...

Comment: It's the newest video. I understand that the picture remains "sensible" for specific cases if we actually draw out, but I want a rigorous proof that covers all cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This discrete surface "contained" into an hexagonal box with sidelength $N$ (see an example on Fig. 1) is perfectly known in terms of a set of regularly spaced level lines at heights $k+1/2, k=0,1,... N-1$ (see dotted lines on figure 2, in connection with figure 1).

[image]

*Fig. 1: A realization.*

[image]

*Fig. 2: The associated paths.*

In fact, we can think in terms of an algorithm able to build any such set of regularly spaced level lines, and associate to this set the adequate lozenges (or rhombi), providing the final 3D visual interpretation.

Here is the principle of this algorithm for a "side-$N$" hexagon (here $N=8$):

- Initialize the hexagon with a "all blue color".
- Build $N$ paths connecting the LHS to the RHS ; a path being a broken line with slopes $\pm 1/2$ with two constraints a) they must be non-intersecting b) for each path, the $k$-th line segment on the LHS is connected to the $k$-th line segment on the right (otherwise said, each broken line has the sum of its $\pm 1/2$ slopes equal to $0$).
- Now the graphical part: for each path, in the case of a $+1/2$ slope (resp. $-1/2$ slope) associate to it an ascending yellow rhombus (resp. a descending red rhombus).

Almost magically, in fact very naturally, the blue sectors appear as flat "plateaus" or "mesas".

**Remarks:**

1. This issue is connected to important combinatorial problems, for example the so-called "Aztech diamond" configuration; see the very interesting slideshow [here](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/%7Ebbecker/amf2018/talk_amf18_Lille_kuijlaars.pdf) where our algorithm is described as well.
2. I am indebted to one of my students who has written on my demand the program that has given these figures... funnily just some days ago!
3. The site "Art Of Problem Solving" uses this kind of "cube piles" as a (default) visual code for each of its participants. See for example [here] (https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3h1170419p5617947).
4. Working on hexagonal grids necessitates sometimes specifing coding means: have a look at [this site](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do you know every single tiling has a corresponding "path representation"?

Comment: Because, proceeding progressively from left to right, the right neigbour of the "current" lozenge has either a "descending" or an "ascending" right neighbor.

Comment: I think I understand the reasoning now. Thank you so much.

Comment: It seems to me that Fig. 2 is the basis of the proof, which is fundamentally two-dimensional, while Fig. 1 is merely an attractive visual consequence of the theorem, rather than any kind of logical source of a proof. This is why I think the question is an interesting one; I had the same skepticism about the method of "proof" described in the question.

Comment: It also seems to me that the comment about "descending" and "ascending" right neighbors is a necessary part of the argument, along with the observation that each vertical edge of the grid along the left-hand side must have a "descending" or "ascending" right neighbor. Moreover, if you have a "descending" or "ascending" lozenge in a finite region, that region must have a vertical edge, so there can be no such lozenges in any of the regions that are not part of your $N$ paths. (These might be "obvious" observations, but for MSE I think it is OK to state the obvious.)

Comment: @David K I agree. I realize now that a clearer description would have used the  "Dick paths" concept and  an ordering among them.